# Scatterplots in Plotly/R: Domains and Scales

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot

Why do we need to use **AsIs** operator (i.e. I(x)) while defining symbols, colors and sizes in **plotly** graphs? The explanation in the official documentation is rather sketchy and obscure.

Let's say, I want to get standard point characters. In the Base plotting system I would type something like this:

```
plot(x = 1:25, y = 1:25, pch = 1:25)
```

A similar command in plotly gives only 6 characters instead of 25:

```
plot_ly(x = 1:25, y = 1:25, symbol = 1:25)
```

To reproduce Base plotting system, one needs to pass the vector 1:25 to **AsIs** operator:

```
plot_ly(x = 1:25, y = 1:25, symbol = I(1:25))
```

So, why couldn't we simply pass 1:25 to plot_ly, like we did that in plot?

Comment: It gives you warnings.:`The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more than 6
becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 25. Consider specifying shapes manually
if you must have them. ` `I()` just enforces using 25 shapes.

Comment: Thank you. I know that, but I have no clue what is the "shape palette" and why it can't deal with more than 6 values. Perhaps, I simply don't understand the way, this palette works.